# Unable to get laravel site on nginx to route correctly

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, nginx

Hello I'm just getting started with nginx and laravel on windows and trying to get this all setup locally.  Right now, I am able to get to my laravel site by going to http://localhost/project-name-laravel/public/index.php.  I've tried a number of ways to get the site to load without the public/index.php and nothing seems to work.  Currently when I navigate to public it gives me a "no input file specified" error and omitting public and index.php does the same.

Additionally if anyone knows why the codeigniter project will not load while navigating to http://localhost/project-name (returns 403) and only works when I add the home controller such as http://localhost/project-name/home.  I performed the initial steps to move the index.php out of the public folder.

**Folder structure**

```
--C:\nginx
  --html
    --project-name          #code igniter
    --project-name-laravel  #laravel
```

**nginx.conf**

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         "C:/nginx/html";

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   "C:/nginx/html";
        }
        
        # CodeIgniter
        location /project-name {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /project-name/index.php?$is_args$args;
        }
        
        # Laravel
        location /project-name-laravel {
            root    /project-name-laravel/public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try creating a .htaccess file in your project directory root?

Answer (score 0):

The root in nginx config should be `root  "C:/nginx/html/project-name-laravel/public"`

Comment: I tried changing the root under the laravel location and same error when removing index.php "no input file specified".

Comment: You need to set up virtual host in your machine!